# Как выбирать алгоритмы по эффективности в разных ситуациях?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Изучаю книгу Кормена, параллельно изучая Java. Там хорошо описаны алгоритмы, но такой вопрос по ним. Есть кучу сортировок, поиска нужных элементов и пр. Вопрос: как понять, какой именно алгоритм использовать в ситуации, если у них у всех время T примерно одинаково и находится в зазоре O(N) <= t <= O(N^2)? Самому графики составлять и время замерять?

Comment: ` время T примерно одинаково и находится в зазоре` ну ничего себе вывод... Вы поняли, что такое асимптотическая сложность?

Comment: 99.9% времени программист использует стандартные алгоритмы и структуры данных. Чтобы понять, что конкретно применять в этих 99.9% случаях, достаточно разобраться в стандартных структурах данных и временем их работы. Чтобы решать нетривиальные задачи, которые составляют 0.01% от всех задач, надо не только хорошо знать теорию (можете начать с книги Стивена Скиены - Алгоритмы. Руководство по разработке), но и прорешать пару-тройку тысяч задач на практике.

Comment: А знание всяких динамических, фиббоначиевых куч надобно в Java?

Comment: Знаю, что такое асимптотика. Да, алгоритмы, имеющие ограниченную сверху сложность O(N^2), могут сильно разниться, например, T(N) = N^2 - N + 1 и T(N) = N^2. Просто я уже хотел в OriginPro графики строить, ведь еще время зависит и от изначальной  упорядоченности элементов

Answer (score 2):

`в зазоре O(N) <= t <= O(N^2)` - пропасть огромного размера.

Если линейные и `O(nlogn)` алгоритмы обычно пригодны для обработки данных любого размера, то квадратичные - только для ограниченных размеров (для сортировок это десятки и сотни элементов).

Можете посчитать, сколько понадобится времени на выполнение  сортировки, если имеется N элементов (10, 100, 1000, 10000 и т.д.), одна операция занимает, скажем, 1 наносекунду (10^-9 c), при количествe операций `a*N, a*N*log(N), a*N^2`, где коэффициент `a` поварьируйте (например, логлинейный возьмите с a=100, а квадратичный с a=5)

Про изначальную упорядоченность - это относится как к лучшему и худшему случаю (в таблице ниже), так и к "натуральному поведению" - например, вставки быстро работают на почти упорядоченных данных, teamsort, или natural mergesort, а обычному mergesort - пофиг.

В английской вики есть [таблица сравнения алгоритмов сортировки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), так что можно подобрать по конкретной ситуации.

Например если требуется сортировать десятки элементов - хорошо подойдёт сортировка вставками. Если при этом сами элементы большие по размеру - выбором, т.к. у неё меньше обменов, перемещения данных.

В большинстве случаев стоит выбирать сортировку, встроенную в стандартную библиотеку используемого языка - обычно это быстрая сортировка или teamsort, иногда слиянием (для случая, когда нужна стабильная сортировка).

Comment: Вот прямо сейчас сижу и пытаюсь по Кормену разобрать mergeSort. Как я понимаю, я должен их, во-первых, знать, а во-вторых, знать, когда их применить, в какой ситуации и почему. Сортировка слиянием вроде использует много дополнительной памяти. Я тут уже создавал тему, хотел бы на Java писать серверные приложения, поэтому думаю, что без алгоритмов будет тяжко.

Comment: Достаточно знать общие принципы,а не досконально реализацию. Отметьте для себя - довольно быстрая, без худшего случая, стабильная, требует памяти. Обратите только внимание на используемую в mergesort процедуру merge слияния сортированных массивов, это может пригодиться.

Comment: Да, свойства важные. Я смотрю на общее решение в КОрмене и пытаюсь сам код воспроизвести(в серых табличках у него) на Java, но пока не идет. Я, как понимаю, должен знать свойства алгоритмов, которые Вы назвали.

Comment: Блин, на английской Вики выучить сложности алгоритмов нереал. Еще надо каждый алгоритм. Пипец.

Comment: Да не надо их учить, просто знать, где посмотреть и общие тенденции.

Comment: А реализацию спрашивать будут? Если на стажера пойду?

Comment: Блин, я уже полвечера сижу с этим алгоритмом. Это полная ж.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что сейчас изучаю mergeSort и не могу понять, как реализовать функцию merge. Это полная Ж. Я тупой.

Comment: Ну вот стоят две колонны солдат по росту, нужно создать общую по росту. Просто на каждом шаге выбираете более высокого бойца и отправляете в новую колонну.